# Jupyter Notebook: Print 2d array, where each and every row and column is in a single line

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

When I try to print a 28 x 28 2d array using the code

```
print(x_test[0])
```

I get output like this:

```
    [[  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0  84 185 159 151  60  36   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0 222 254 254 254 254 241 198 198 198 198 198 198
  198 198 170  52   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0  67 114  72 114 163 227 254 225 254 254 254 250
  229 254 254 140   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  17  66  14  67  67  67  59
   21 236 254 106   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   83 253 209  18   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  22
  233 255  83   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 129
  254 238  44   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  59 249
  254  62   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 133 254
  187   5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   9 205 248
   58   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 126 254 182
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  75 251 240  57
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  19 221 254 166   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3 203 254 219  35   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  38 254 254  77   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  31 224 254 115   1   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 133 254 254  52   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  61 242 254 254  52   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 121 254 254 219  40   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 121 254 207  18   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]]
```

I have even tried other methods using pandas Dataframe. But it doesn't display some of the output values. All I just want is a 28 rows and 28 columns for my 28 x 28 2d array. I'm using python on Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a little printing function to do this.  You will need to do a little bit of formatting, and also watch the window width.

```
In [4]: my_matrix = [[1,23,0], [55,4,-1], [0,0,2]]                              

In [5]: for row in my_matrix: 
   ...:     for item in row: 
   ...:         print('%3d ' % item, end="") 
   ...:     print() 
   ...:                                                                         
  1  23   0 
 55   4  -1 
  0   0   2
```

if you have 28 columns and you use 3 spaces per number for alignment and a space between, it's getting kinda wide, so watch the wrap-around.